# Локальная константа времени выполнения

Tags: c#, константа, дизайн-языка

В C++ для определения локальной константы времени выполнения можно написать так:

```
const auto c = f();
```

Далее, все попытки изменить `c` будут приводить к ошибке компиляции.

В C# такой возможности нет. Можно использовать `readonly` член подобным образом, но не локальную константу.

Почему существует такое ограничение (в чём причина отсутствия локальных констант а-ля C++) и какое каноническое решение имеется для обеспечения локальной константности времени выполнения на C#? Неужели для этого надо создавать отдельный read-only интерфейс?

Comment: потому что в c# Нет констант - они подставляются на этапе компиляции

Comment: [как вариант](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11054666/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy ну `readonly` же в ран-тайме задаётся. И потом это поле менять нельзя.

Comment: тогда я не понял вопроса :-) я понял, что тебя чем-то не устраивает readonly

Comment: @Grundy тем, что он только для членов, а я хочу локальную константу.

Comment: Ага, значит я вопрос не так понял :)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/115

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стоит отметить, что по локальным readonly-переменным есть [официальный proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/115). Фича опоздала к C# 7, но у нее все шансы войти в C# 8.

Со стороны CLR для реализации нет никаких ограничений - readonly locals, как и все фичи C# со времен .NET 4.0 - это compile-time фичи - т.к. версия рантайма с тех пор не поменялась.

По сути, proposal сводится к нескольким пунктам:

- возможности помечать *параметры* как `readonly`
- возможности помечать *переменные* как `readonly`
- шорткату `let` - эквиваленту `readonly var`

---

Локальные readonly, как и неизменяемые `foreach iteration variable` - это, прежде всего, защита от дурака/ошибки копипасты. И уже потом - способ указать компилятору на возможную оптимизацию замыканий.

На мой взгляд, сама по себе возможность вручную приписывать readonly к локальным переменным только ради в качестве защиты от потенциальной ошибки - неудобна для реального использования. Достаточно вспомнить о `final` в Java. Поэтому без шортката `let` фича будет достаточно бесполезной - ее будут использовать фанаты "безопасного кода" - те, кто сейчас принципиально не использует `var` и явно вписывают типы во всех упоминаниях генерика.

Остальные пойдут по пути наименьшего сопротивления - гораздо дешевле и проще исправить одну ошибку раз в месяц, чем приписывать readonly к каждой переменной. Ну и опять же, тесты, при правильном применении, решают проблему ошибок копипасты.

Более надежный способ защиты реализован, например, в F#, где локальные значения по умолчанию неизменяемы, а `=` вне объявления значения вообще не работает как оператор присвоения.

```
let x = 1
x = 2 // This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'
```

Для изменения значения разработчику придется сделать дополнительные телодвижения, как в строчке где переменная объявлена, так и в строчке, где переменная изменяется.

```
let mutable x = 1
x <- 2
```

Сам язык подталкивает его к тому, чтобы объявить еще одно значение, а не менять существующее. Одна из [трех добродетелей программиста](http://wiki.c2.com/?LazinessImpatienceHubris) - лень - уберегает его от ошибки.

А просто так дописывать readonly к переменным, "как бы чего не вышло" - никто, кроме особых фанатов, не будет - из соображений той же лени.

Comment: Ну в джаве же пишут...

Comment: А что насчёт решения в существующем варианте языка?

Comment: @Qwertiy в джаве пишут фанаты порядка. писать перед каждой переменной дополнительное ключевое слово только ради того, чтобы язык не дал тебе же поменять значение этой переменной - это странно и противоестествено

Comment: @PashaPash, полностью согласен. Но джависты почему-то любят его писать...

Comment: Кстати, оно могло бы позволить в лямбды отдавать ссылки по значению :) Как, впрочем, и сделано в джаве.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не знаю почему джависты любят писать final (кроме случая с лямбдами - но они делали это и до появления лямбд). на мой взгляд java - это застывший в развитии язык, там много чего делают только потому, что 20 лет назад кто-то предположил что "так будет лучше". По поводу лямб - в proposal об этом кстати тоже сказано, причем один из основных аргументов за readonly locals

Comment: @alexolut в существующем варианте языка решения нет :(

Comment: @PashaPash, но ведь компилятор может и сам определить, что в переменную не пишут - для этого ему не нужно ключевое слово. Ведь он же не будет верить программисту на слово, а будет проверять, что readonly не нарушается.

Comment: @PashaPash а вариант с использование ReadOnly интерфейса? (озвучено в вопросе). Какая-то каноническая защита должна быть от модификации ведь.

Comment: @alexolut вопрос же про локальные переменные. вариантов реализации не через переменные - сколько угодно. Но это как из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: @Qwertiy обнаружить запись в readonly просто (одной проверкой). а вот обнаружить отсутствие записи в не-readonly, да еще и в общем виде - немного сложее. Но никто не мешает вам дописать это в roslyn и оформить пуллреквестом :)

Comment: Про каноническое решение в вопросе тоже сказано, и это важная часть вопроса на мой взгляд.

Comment: @alexolut топикастер не утверждает, что readonly-интерфейсы - это каноническое решение. Он спрашивает, есть ли такое решение. :) Ответ - нет, не существует канонического решения обеспечения readonly для локальных переменных. Не поддерживается и все тут. Если нужно readonly - стоит использовать то, у чего есть поддержка readonly.

Comment: @alexolut если честно - я даже не до конца понимаю что там имеется ввиду под решением через Readonly-интерфейсы. Скорее всего сделать переменную полем мини-класса, выделить у него интерфейс с геттером, и использовать инстанс этого класса вместо переменной. Какой-то дичайший овердизайн получается.

Comment: Имеется в виду нечто [такое](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_interface). Т.е. какие шаги имеет смысл предпринять для достижения эффекта локальной константности. Или просто все забивают болт на то, что переменная от которой ожидают (логической) константности может быть изменена или отмазываются фразами типа "значит ваш метод слишком длинный, если вам нужна локальная константа"?

Comment: @alexolut вот именно это решение я и описал выше - оно не имеет никакого отношения к локальным переменным. и от записи нового значения оно тоже не защищает. т.е. это вообще не решение той проблемы, которую описал топикастер. а просто пример обычно иммутабельности объектов, которая в C# встречается достаточно часто (но при этом все равно не имеет никакого отношение к локальным константам)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50386/discussion-between-pashapash-and-alexolut).

Comment: @PashaPash: Уже запланировано к разработке, апдейт: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/188

Answer (score 8):

Ответы: [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/443844/2881286), и [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/443899/2881286)

Одна из причин - отсутствие поддержки CLR для локальных переменных только для чтения. *Readonly* переводится в CLR/CLI `initonly` опкод. Этот флаг может быть применен только к полям и не имеет смысла для локальных переменных. Фактически, применение этого кода к локальным переменным скорее всего сделает код непроверяемым.

Это не значит, что C# не может реализовать это. Но это добавляет два смысла для одной и той же языковой конструкции. Версия для локальных переменных не будет иметь в CLR эквивалентного отображения.

---

Обращаясь к ответу Jared'а, это возможно может быть compile-time фичей - компилятор будет запрещать тебе писать в переменную после первоначального объявления (которое должно включать присвоение).

Есть ли в этом польза? Потенциальная - но не большая, если быть честным. Если ты не можешь сказать будет или нет присваивание еще где-то в методе, то твой метод слишком большой.

Как бы то ни было, в Java есть эта особенность (при использовании модификатора `final`) и я *очень* редко видел его использование в случаях отличных от разрешения использования переменной в внутреннем анонимном классе - и где это было использовано это давало скорее впечатление беспорядка, чем полезной информации.

---

в качестве обходного пути, если очень хочется, только на свой страх и риск есть такой:

[Настолько отличный, насколько ужасный пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27570162/2881286)

В качестве run-time константы можно использовать переменную в блоке итератора:

```
public void f() 
{
  foreach (int n in new int[] { getNum() }) // n declared constant
  {
    n = 3; // won't compile: "error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'n' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"
  }
}
```

Comment: Какое "элегантное" решение, однако.

Comment: @alexolut, честно говоря даже не думал о таком :-) Но хотелось бы конечно увидеть какое-нибудь пояснение почему readonly Только на уровне класса

Comment: Надо макрос сделать и будет "шоколад" (с привкусом) :-D

Comment: @alexolut, обновил ответ

Comment: Такое ощущение, что я эти ответы уже читал раньше:) Кстати, тут недавно был ответ про F# и утверждение про отсутствие констант CLR на этом фоне кажется странным.

Comment: @alexolut, так у них 9 год стоит :) а с foreach - 14

Comment: то есть, где-то в 2019 видимо сделают нормальные плюсовые константы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50367/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexolut).